# How do I list my unwatched iTunes purchases on Apple TV?

Tags: appletv

I'm thinking of "cutting the cord" and getting an Apple TV, and then buying an iTunes "season pass" for each of the TV shows I'm watching.

Does Apple TV provide a good way to list/find the episodes that I haven't watched yet, without having to wade through all the series, seasons, and episodes that I've already watched?  As time goes on, it seems like there would be a build-up of watched shows that would make it harder and harder to find the unwatched ones.

Apparently Hulu has a feature like this called "watchlist", but I can't find any information on a similar feature for shows purchased a-la-carte from Apple.  The closest I've seen is that you can apparently hide past purchases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple TV used to have a feature that let you see a list of unwatched shows. Unfortunately, no more.

Just create a smart playlist with the criterion of "plays" equals zero, or less than 1.

Comment: My answer was edited without my knowledge or permission. In short, Apple designs user interfaces in a way that requires no approvals, checks, or tests—it was set up that way by Steve Jobs before he died and he explained his rationale at a WWDC.